# Customizing make target based on from where it was entered

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a variable like $@ which would contain instead of current target the target which required current target? Below is a simple example of what kind of functionality I am looking for. Basically "make foo" would create a directory foo, "make bar" would create bar and "make both" both. So far I haven't found anything which would enable this kind of customization.

```
foo: foobar
    do stuff
bar: foobar
    do other stuff
both: foo bar
    ....

foobar:
    mkdir <foo or bar>
```

Found one solution, pattern rules.

```
foo: from_foo
    @echo "This is foo"
from_%:
    @echo "Called from $(lastword $(subst _, ,$@))"
    @echo "Simpler version... $*"
```

Comment: Make examines entries in the current working directory. Using a directory as a target is usually not a good idea because the directory's time stamp will be updated every time you modify it, while you usually really want to check whether the directory's *contents* are up to date. A common mechanism for this is to create a flag file in the directory, and make that the target.

Comment: I think you can read the value of `%` using `$*`, instead of messing with `$@`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat good point. That's a lot simpler than parsing from target name.

Comment: Agreed listing directories as prerequisites is virtually never what you want.  A directory's modification time is updated whenever a file in that directory is added, removed, or renamed, but NOT when a file is changed.  So by listing a directory as a prerequisite you will consider the target out of date if any file in that directory is added, removed, or renamed (but not updated).  This can be extremely useful, but only in very unusual and limited situations.  It's never useful if all you want is "this directory exists".

Comment: Just to answer the question asked: there is no way in make to find the name of the "parent" target.  There could be extremely bogus tricks to play with secondary expansion and `eval` but I don't want to even try it.